# How do I set the local document root in Apache?

Tags: apache

So this is my directory structure

```
/
/test
    index.php
    blah.php
blah.php
```

So in `/test/index.php` I have a link such as this

```
<a href="/blah.php">Link</a>
```

but I want it to link to `/test/blah.php`, not the `blah.php` in the root directory.  Basically, I want to set a local document root.   Is this possible to set this using `.htaccess` or in the `httpd.conf`?

Comment: Do you want to make /test the root of your whole site, or only the root of links on pages in that directory?

Comment: Only the root of links on pages in that directory

Comment: I guess I didn't ask what I meant to ask. Are you trying to make a self-contained site inside that /test directory, that doesn't use pages outside of /test? If so, meder's solution will probably work. Otherwise, I don't see any options besides the ones I mention in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an `a` tag on `/test/index.php` has its `href` set to `/blah.php`, then it's the *browser* that's interpreting that as pointing to a file in the document root. So you can't achieve what you want without changing the way you're generating the `href` attribute.

You have a couple of options for this:

- You can omit the forward slash to generate links relative to the current URL instead of the document root. A link in `/test/index.php` pointing to `blah.php` will be interpreted as `/test/blah.php`.
- You can write some custom code to generate your links. You could have a function `my_special_link ($link)` that takes in `blah.php` and prepends the current file's directory, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your httpd.conf or better yet put it in a virtualhost directory

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName blah.localhost
DocumentRoot C:\web\test
</VirtualHost>
```

In WINDOWS\System\system32\etc\bin or somewhere ( LOOK for 'hosts' file ), edit hosts file so it has

```
127.0.0.1 blah.localhost
```

Restart apache and go to blah.localhost in the browser.